# Proving an equality with Cramer's rule

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Let $b$ and $e$ two positive vectors on $\mathbb{R}^2.$ Furthermore, let $A,\,Z\in\mathbb{R}^{2,2}$ where $Z$ is a diagonal matrix with non-positive elements. How can we prove the following identity using Cramer's rule?

\begin{equation}
1 + b^TZ(I - AX)^{-1}e = \frac{det(I-(A-eb^T)X)}{det(I-AX)},
\end{equation}
where $I$ is the $2\times 2$ identical matrix and $det(I-AX) \neq 0.$

Can someone gime a hint?

Comment: Should that be $e$ instead of $w$?

Comment: @BenGrossmann Yes!

Comment: Is there any particular reason that you want to solve this using Cramer's rule?

Comment: A possible way to start: consider the case where $b = (1,0)$ and $Z$ is invertible. We can see that $b^TZ(I - AX)^{-1}e$ is the first entry of the solution to the equation
$$
(I - AX)Z^{-1}x = e.
$$
Therefore, Cramer's rule yields
$$
b^TZ(I - AX)^{-1}e = \frac{\det((I - AX) - (I - AX)bb^T + eb^T)}{\det(I - AX).}
$$